# Why doesn't $(window).height(); return a value, but $(document).height(); does?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to get current window height. I intend to set a variable with this value, and update the value upon resize. For some reason, $(window).height(); always returns zero, but  $(document).height(); returns a value. Why would this be?

(code snipped for brevity)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function drawGrid() {

    var context = document.getElementById("gridCanvas").getContext("2d");

    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = height/2/8;
    alert(height);

    $(window).resize(function () {
        // do some stuff
    });

        // do some cool drawing stuff

    }

    drawGrid();

});
```

Comment: I get a height back in document.ready http://jsfiddle.net/zpu2c/3/

Comment: The alert I have right after asking for the window height reads 0..

Comment: @JohnKoerner because your code and contents are simple enough so that when document is ready, window is loaded already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

can you try

```
$(window).load(function () {
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

and see if it works. I think you have to wait window finish loading if you want to get window's size.

Comment: I wasn't sure why either.. It worked right away with no problems.. Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

$(window).height() and also $(window).width() return 0 in IE 
when in compatibility mode.
try to use $(document).height() or $(document).width() instead.