# div A fixed height, div B below adjusting to window

Tags: html, css

I have a header and a content div. The header height is fixed and the content div I want to adjust to the windo height, but if its content exceeds the window height therre shall be y-scroll bars for the content div.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmKbn/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom">

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.top{
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
}

.bottom{
    min-height:100px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: so you need to set content height by javascript or fixed content height by css and excess content beyond that height generates y-scroll bars??

Comment: I was wondering if there is a pure CSS solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is either going to need `display: table;` or a new CSS3 feature - [`calc()`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

What do you need to support? If it is only new browsers, you could try this:

```
.bottom {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dmKbn/3/)

Comment: @kaputu - You can also easily do this without using `calc()` or `display: table;`, if you need support for older browsers, just set `.bottom { position: absolute; top: 100px; bottom: 0px; }`. Here's a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dmKbn/10/).

Answer (score 1):

Use calc() - http://html5please.com/#calc

with 100px being your top bar

```
height: 100%; /** older browsers **/
max-height: 100%; /** older browsers **/
max-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100x); /** Chrome / Safari 6 **/
max-height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px); /** FF 4-15  **/
max-height: calc(100% - 100px); /** FF 16+, IE 9+, and future other browsers **/
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="top"></div>
<div style="overflow:auto;height:100%;position:absolute;">
<div class="bottom">

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....
</div>
</div>

.top{
height:100px;
width: 100%;
background-color: grey;


}

.bottom{
    min-height:100px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: red;

}
```

Comment: no, then I have a scrollbar at the window, but not at the content div. Test here: [jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/dmKbn/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:absolute` and `max-height:100%` to `.bottom` class,

Then the changed class will be

```
.bottom{
min-height:100px;
width: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
background-color: red;
position:absolute;
max-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: then fix height for outer div and get that div height from jquery as `$("#divid").height()` which will give height in pixels. 
Assign that height to the `.bottom` div in jquery as

`$(".bottom").css({
"height":"obtained-value";
});`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035819/window-height-vs-document-height

I think this may help you :)

Comment: 100% height for any container will always tries to occupy the parent container's height. So if you fix the parent container's height, then the above answered modified class will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

the scroll bars will automatically added if content exceeds the window size. To add content height to window height try to use the javascript to get window size and set it within onload method of page instead of setting it inside css.

Answer (score 0):

To fulfill your requirement, we need to use jQuery.

like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var height = $(window).height() - $(".top").height();
   $('.bottom').css('height', height+'px');

});
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/dmKbn/6/)